# Silverstripe - FormSchema with submissions and validation

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm trying to make use of the new FormSchema class in Silverstripe 4 but I'm having a tough time with the workflow for submitting the form. I've been able to return the schema and state, but when submitting the form back to the controller is where I run in to issues. Here is some example code:

```php
class TestController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'schema',
        'TestForm'    
    ];

    public function schema(HTTPRequest $request) {
        $schema = new FormSchema();
        return json_encode($schema->getMultipartSchema(['schema', 'state', 'errors'], "FormID", $this->TestForm()));
    }

    public function TestForm() {

        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name', 'Name'),
            EmailField::create('Email', 'Email')
        );

        $actions = FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('doTestSubmit', 'Submit')
        );

        $required = RequiredFields::create(['Name', 'Email']);

        return Form::create($this, 'TestForm', $fields, $actions, $required);

    }

    public function doTestSubmit($data, $form) {
        return json_encode(array('response' => 'The form validated and was submitted.'));
    }

}
```

So in this scenario hitting `/schema` returns `TestForm` schema in json then the front end renders the form. Submitting the form sends the data back to `/TestForm` where it is validated. If the submission is valid it'll continue to `doTestSubmit` and return the response. That's great! But, if the submission is not valid then `TestForm` attempts to return the form and not the schema with the validation messages.

I first though about using a condition in `TestForm()` like `if($this->request->isPOST())` or `if($form->validationResult()->isValid())` but it doesn't seem like the proper way to handle it.

Any input or a simple code sample would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use the standard Form > Form Post > Form Action way, you have to create an own Form Handler that validates the form. Like this (untested code):

```
public function doTestSubmit($request) {
    $form = $this->TestForm()
    $form->loadDataFrom($request->postVars);
    if(!$form->validationResult()->isValid()) {
        $formSchema = new FormSchema();
        $state = $formSchema->getState($form);
        return json_encode($state);
    }
    //Valid, continue
}
```